# Can't load HTTP from HTTPS - same domain

Tags: .htaccess, http-headers, apache2

I get this error in my console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://example.com/shop/xx/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

How can I fix this?

I have added this to my .htaccess:

And enabled mod_header + restarted apache.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
     Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You should be using https for the origin as well.

Comment: Can you show how you will put that in the mod_header

Comment: No I mean make the request from https.